# Images Not Loading/Displaying

Tags: php, html, css

I am facing a critical issue during my project. I am working on MVC model and in the view folder my css sheet is present. on which i put a code for the body element like this

```
body{
    margin-left:250px;
    background-image:url("/image/background.jpg");  
}
```

MVC structure is like this

```
MVC---
    -
    - View
      - css
        -stylesheet.css
    - Controller
    - Model
    -image
    index.php
```

how could i able to fetch the code on css .. it's absolutely supporting me to fetch images on my html pages when i anchoring them. but it's not be fetching by stylesheet. please also specify the reason behind it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body{
    margin-left:250px;
    background-image:url("../../image/background.jpg");  
}
```

your style-sheet file is `view/css` so you need to get back with `../` two times to access image folder.

you can use this as

```
@base-url: "../../image"; /* path to image/ you can use http url also */
background-image: url("@{base-url}/background.jpg");
```

Comment: where is your css folder? inside View?

Comment: how you accessing your stylesheet? url like?

Comment: <link type="text/css" href="view/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: your style-sheet file is `view/css` so you need to get back with `../` two times to access image folder.

Comment: For CSS it is good to use the full URL eg:`http://folder/folder1/image/background.jpg`.This is because the full path will vary is you are using the same style in different files in different folder.

Comment: ../ is good if you are going to use that external stylesheet on a single page.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this approach and always link relative to the root folder. I would look at why your original path of `"/image/background.jpg"` doesn't work. Might be something to do with your MVC framework.